# localhost vs hostname

Tags: networking, android

I am confused with `localhost(127.0.0.1)` and `hostname(127.0.1.1)` ,when I try for

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   JAZZ
```

and in case of `ifconfig` also I got about `localhost(lo:local loopback, 127.0.0.1`) ,

But when I tried this (`cat /etc/hosts`) on my android phone, by a bash emulator I got only 127.0.0.1 ,

```
android@user$cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1            localhost
```

Why there is no `hostname` in my android phone ??

Comment: This is not about Ubuntu. Ask on [unix.se] or [android.se].

Comment: Thanx@muru ,well Is there any way to transfer this question to Unix & Linux or Android Enthusiasts??

Comment: You can flag it for moderator attention and ask for it to be migrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mobile is rooted and have a terminal emulator installed then you can check the host name using command

```
getprop net.hostname
```

To change host name type:

```
setprop net.hostname new_name
```

Comment: Thanx @Vembu ,it worked ..well Is this hostname is associated with 127.0.1.1 ?